# Accessing row in a 2-D tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have the following code of an incredibly simple neural network (this code is actually an adaptation for an easy question):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device("cpu:0"):
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    nNodes = 3
    inputDim = 1

    rowIdxs = np.zeros([nNodes, nNodes])
    colIdxs = np.zeros([nNodes, nNodes])
    for rowIdx in range(nNodes):
        for colIdx in range(nNodes):
            rowIdxs[rowIdx, colIdx] = rowIdx
            colIdxs[rowIdx, colIdx] = colIdx

    rowIdxs = np.reshape(rowIdxs, [-1])
    colIdxs = np.reshape(colIdxs, [-1])

    # build a matrix with nNodes x nNodes elements
    # with each row i containing the distance from node i to all the other nodes
    distances = np.zeros([nNodes, nNodes])
    for i in range(nNodes):
        for j in range(nNodes):
            distances[i, j] = ((rowIdxs[i] - rowIdxs[j]) ** 2 + (colIdxs[i] - colIdxs[j]) ** 2)
    print('distances=', distances)

    # tensorflow constant from distances matrix
    distances_ = tf.constant(distances, dtype=tf.float32)

    # w corresponds to a weight matrix in a neural network
    w = tf.random_uniform((nNodes, inputDim), 0.0, 1.0)

    # x corresponds to the input to the network
    x = tf.random_uniform((1, inputDim), 0.0, 1.0)

    xx = tf.tile(x, [nNodes,1])
    print('w', w.shape)
    print('x', x.shape)
    print('xx', xx.shape)

    # differences between weights and input vector
    diff = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(xx, w)), 1)
    print('diff.shape', diff.shape)


    # index of the best matching unit
    bmu = tf.arg_min(diff, 0)       

    # Now I need to access the distances from BMU to the other nodes
    slice = tf.slice(distances_, [bmu, 0], [bmu, -1])

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(slice)
    print('slice=', slice.eval())
    print('diff', diff.eval())
    print('bmu=', bmu.eval())
```

Basically, given an input `x`, compare it to the weights `w` and choose the node `BMU` with the minimum differences.

I have several problems with that code:

**1. sometimes it works without errors sometimes it raises an exception.**

**When it DOES NOT work**, the output is this:

```
distances= 
 [[ 0.  1.  4.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.]]

w (3, 1)
x (1, 1)
xx (3, 1)
diff.shape (3,)

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected size[0] in [0, 1], but got 2
 [[Node: Slice = Slice[Index=DT_INT64, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Const, Slice/begin, Slice/size)]]
```

The full stack follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "D:\python\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected size[0] in [0, 1], but got 2
     [[Node: Slice = Slice[Index=DT_INT64, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Const, Slice/begin, Slice/size)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workspace/LiClipse Workspace/kerasPython/exercises/testIndexing.py", line 44, in <module>
    sess.run(slice)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected size[0] in [0, 1], but got 2
     [[Node: Slice = Slice[Index=DT_INT64, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Const, Slice/begin, Slice/size)]]

Caused by op 'Slice', defined at:
  File "D:/workspace/LiClipse Workspace/kerasPython/exercises/testIndexing.py", line 39, in <module>
    slice = tf.slice(distances_, [bmu, 0], [bmu, -1])
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 561, in slice
    return gen_array_ops._slice(input_, begin, size, name=name)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 3053, in _slice
    name=name)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2395, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1264, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected size[0] in [0, 1], but got 2
     [[Node: Slice = Slice[Index=DT_INT64, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Const, Slice/begin, Slice/size)]]
```

**When it works**

```
w (3, 1)
x (1, 1)
xx (3, 1)
diff.shape (3,)
slice= [[ 1.  0.  1.]]
diff [ 0.29777944  0.08669317  0.09722018]
bmu= 0
```

`bmu` is wrong, it should be `1`, but the slice is correct.

Sometimes I get this:

```
w (3, 1)
x (1, 1)
xx (3, 1)
diff.shape (3,)
slice= []
diff [ 0.33319855  0.12426794  0.49753141]
bmu= 1
```

`bmu` is 1, but slice is empty.

**2. When I switch to the GPU, I have an exception telling me I cannot use `bmu` for indexing.**
Starting with `with tf.device("gpu:0"):`, I get this:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device to node 'Slice/size': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
     [[Node: Slice/size = Pack[N=2, T=DT_INT64, axis=0, _device="/device:GPU:0"](ArgMin, Slice/size/1)]]
```

The full stack trace follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "D:\python\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'Slice/size': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
     [[Node: Slice/size = Pack[N=2, T=DT_INT64, axis=0, _device="/device:GPU:0"](ArgMin, Slice/size/1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workspace/LiClipse Workspace/kerasPython/exercises/testIndexing.py", line 45, in <module>
    sess.run(slice)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'Slice/size': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
     [[Node: Slice/size = Pack[N=2, T=DT_INT64, axis=0, _device="/device:GPU:0"](ArgMin, Slice/size/1)]]

Caused by op 'Slice/size', defined at:
  File "D:/workspace/LiClipse Workspace/kerasPython/exercises/testIndexing.py", line 40, in <module>
    slice = tf.slice(distances_, [bmu, 0], [bmu, -1])
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 561, in slice
    return gen_array_ops._slice(input_, begin, size, name=name)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 3053, in _slice
    name=name)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 491, in apply_op
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 716, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 923, in _autopacking_conversion_function
    return _autopacking_helper(v, inferred_dtype, name or "packed")
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 886, in _autopacking_helper
    return gen_array_ops._pack(elems_as_tensors, name=scope)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 2041, in _pack
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Pack", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2395, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1264, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device to node 'Slice/size': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
     [[Node: Slice/size = Pack[N=2, T=DT_INT64, axis=0, _device="/device:GPU:0"](ArgMin, Slice/size/1)]]
```

I cannot understand what's happening: I have an idea, but cannot find any reference in the documentation or anywhere else. May be I use the wrong keywords.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: interesting, I use `eval` to trace value of `w` and `x`, and their value change **every step**, maybe this is the problem

Comment: Including a full stacktrace will help diagnose this. Pack is implemented for the GPU, so you should only see this error if your GPU build is broken.

Comment: @xxi What do you mean with "they change at every step" and how can I avoid this issue?

Comment: I have added the full stack trace.

Comment: I just put break point on `w = tf.random_uniform((nNodes, inputDim), 0.0, 1.0)` and use `w.eval()` to trace their value line by line, and their value always change, not sure this is the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.slice` function ([see TF1.15 doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/slice)) takes as third parameter the `size` of the slice, so the line `slice = tf.slice(distances_, [bmu, 0], [bmu, -1])` has to be replaced with

```
slice = tf.slice(distances_, [bmu, 0], [1, -1])
```

The error appears only when `bmu` is higher then half of the number of rows in `distances_`, because in this case a slice of the given size cannot be extracted. Otherwise the computation does not fail but it is incorrect because you don't extract a single row.